# Redis : Max number of clients reached

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I'm using redis with docker, and i have currently this error :

[ioredis] Unhandled error event: ReplyError: ERR max number of clients reached

Someone could help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your redis.conf file there is a configuration:

```
maxclients 10000
```

This means that a maximum of 10K clients can connect to Redis at once.

Generally, this limit is enough and the problem lies on the client side who are opening the connection, doing some operation but not closing the connection when the work is done.
Or if you have some kind of looping logic in your client and you are initializing the connection inside the loop, thus opening multiple connections.

One last thing to keep in mind is, setting

```
maxclients 10000
```

does not gurantee that 10K clients will be able to connect to Redis. If redis server is not able to configure the process file limit to 10K, the maxclients is set to current file limit minus 32

Answer (score 0):

Redis will accept a maximum number of connections. This error is Redis stating it has reached that limit. You can adjust this value in your [redis.conf](https://redis.io/docs/management/config/) file.

That said, I usually see this when folks are connecting to Redis in a loop or in some sort of event and then don't *close* the connection when they are done. You can do this by calling `.quit` from [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis).

Answer (score 0):

On our Redis 2.8 setup. Client used Jedis connection pooling but still got the "max number of clients reach" error. We had to do an additional config setting on the Redis master and slaves. Try adding the `timeout <seconds>` setting. Redis will bin idle clients past the timeout. To check if clients are binned use `redis-cli` and issue the command `client list`, you should notice it decrease after some time.